# Need to convert a normal java application to maven application with datasource configuration

Tags: java, maven, jboss6.x

I had created a java application which is used to fetch some info from DB. Earlier i was using ejb to call this service.

But now, I need to convert this applicatio into MAVEN and I have no clue where to start from.

Also, earlier i was using thinclient JDBC connection to connect to oracle database and now I need to use JBOSS datasource.

Can anyone please guide me what are the steps to follow or some tutorial which i can follow for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to learn the basics of maven you can use this tutorial from Apache Maven: [Maven in 5 minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

Here you have information about how to use a [Jboss Datasource](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)

In JBoss the connection chain will be defined in a XML file in the server, so it doesn't affect to Maven.

I hope this can help you. If you need something else add a comment.